# Why use raw sockets?

Tags: c#, networking, protocols

That is so confusing! We use the TCP/IP protocol in order to achieve reliability, and we use the UDP protocol in order to achieve speed. Do we use raw sockets just to be without a protocol?? What advantage will I get if I use raw sockets?

Comment: Firstly you are starting with the assumption that UDP is only used for speed and TCP for reliability. Secondly, this is an opinion based question which is not a good fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DavidG What are TCP used for other than reliability, and what are UDP used for other than speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apart from a headache, none. Raw sockets is reinventing the application protocol, which would make your code very incompatible with existing standards. One 'advantage' I can think of would be low protocol overhead, since your packets would only contain data specific to your application.

Comment: Then it is useful when making a protocol?

Comment: Yes. There isn't any reason to create a new protocol though. Tcp and Udp cover pretty much all use cases for network data communication. Raw sockets allow access to the complete packet data including the packet header. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket